# Evaluating line integral using The Stokes' Theorem

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals, stokes-theorem

I want to evaluate $$\oint_C (x-z) dx + (x + y) dy + (y+z) dz$$ where $C$ is the ellipse, in which the plane $z=y$ intersects the cylinder $x^2 + y^2 = 1$, oriented counterclockwise as viewed from above. However, solution is somehow wrong. First, I say that the integral equals to $$\oint_{C} \vec F \cdot dr =\int\int_{S} \nabla \times \vec F \cdot \hat n d\sigma $$ where $F= (x-z)\hat i + (x+y)\hat j + (y+z)\hat k$.

Then, I found $\nabla \times \vec F = \hat i - \hat j + \hat k$. Next, I wrote $$\hat n = \frac{\nabla f}{ |\nabla f|} = \frac{-\hat j + \hat k}{\sqrt{2}}$$ and $$d \sigma = \frac{|\nabla f|}{|\nabla f \cdot \hat n|}dxdy$$ where $f(x,y,z) = z-y$. Finally, I got $$\int\int_{S} \nabla \times \vec F \cdot \hat n d\sigma  = \int\int_{x^2 +y^2 \le 1} (\hat i - \hat j + \hat k) \cdot (\frac{-\hat j + \hat k}{\sqrt{2}})dxdy = \int\int_{x^2 +y^2 \le 1} \frac{2}{\sqrt{2}} dxdy = \frac{2}{\sqrt{2}}\pi $$ but the solution must be just $2 \pi.$ Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should simply be,

$ \displaystyle \iint_S (\nabla \times \vec F) \cdot \hat n ~d\sigma = \iint_{x^2 + y^2 \leq 1} (\nabla \times \vec F) \cdot (\nabla f) ~ dA$

$ \displaystyle = \iint_{x^2 + y^2 \leq 1} (\hat i - \hat j + \hat k) \cdot (- \hat j + \hat k) ~dA = 2 \pi$

It is unnecessary to normalize the normal vector as $|\nabla f|$ cancels out. Note that $d\sigma = |\nabla f| ~dA$  where $d \sigma$ is the surface area element and $dA$ is the area element of the projection in xy-plane.

Comment: What happens to $|\nabla f \cdot \hat n|$?

Comment: you mean why we took it out from the denominator? You can have it and normalize it but what about the surface area element? What is the relation between $d \sigma$ and $dA$, if $dA$ is the area element of the circle in xy-plane you are integrating over?

Comment: for example, surface area of the ellipse bound by $C$ in plane $z = y$ is not equal to the area of the unit circle in xy-plane. It is in fact $\sqrt2 \pi$. The way it works is that $d \sigma = |\nabla f| dA$. It is the same factor in both numerator and  denominator and they cancel out. That is why we say it is not necessary to normalize.

Comment: I still do not understand what is going on with $|\nabla f \cdot \hat n|$, unfortunately.

Comment: $(\nabla \times \vec F) \cdot \left(\frac{\nabla f}{||\nabla f||}\right) ~ d\sigma = (\nabla \times \vec F) \cdot \left(\frac{\nabla f}{||\nabla f||}\right) ~ ||\nabla f|| ~ dA$

Comment: Also see if this helps, esp. the part before example 1 on the page - https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/SurfIntVectorField.aspx

Comment: @Ninja : The $\hat n$ in $|\nabla f\cdot\hat n|$ is not the same as the one in $\hat nd\sigma$. In $\hat nd\sigma$, $\hat n$ is the unit normal to the surface on which you're integrating, which you calculated as $\nabla f/|\nabla f|$. But in $\nabla f\cdot\hat n$, $\hat n$ is the normal to the plane in which you're taking $dA$, so in this case just $\hat k$, so that $\nabla f\cdot\hat n=\partial f/\partial z$, which in this case is $1$. (Notice that if this were the same $\hat n$ as before, then $\nabla f\cdot\hat n$ would simplify to $|\nabla f|$, so nobody would write the formula that way.)

Comment: (And I agree with @MathLover that you shouldn't even think about $|\nabla f|$ along the way. Just use $d\vec S=\frac{\nabla f}{|\nabla f\cdot\hat n|}$, where $\hat n$ is normal to the plane in which $dA$ lives. By the way, to distinguish this from the $\hat n$ in $d\vec S=\hat nd\sigma$, I've also seen it written $\hat p$, so you would write $d\vec S=\frac{\nabla f}{|\nabla f\cdot\hat p|}$ instead.)

Comment: @TobyBartels, this was the point I am missing, thank you both!

Comment: @TobyBartels thank you. After reading your comment, I realize what OP's real confusion was.